# Can I set a default Value for the version comment field in a list?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, version-history, version-comments

I'm trying to set a default value on the check in comment in a list in order to guide users to format their comments a certain way. I'm seeking a solution that will work on Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve Side approach:

Create a custom file based on "_layouts/[15]/checkin.aspx" file and add the default value for the comments field. Additionally, to tie this to a particular list, create a custom action(one for Ribbon and one for ECB) that would open your custom "custom-checkin.aspx" file.

JavaScript approach:

```
function addCommentDefaultValue() {
 if (document.URL.indexOf('checkin.aspx') != -1) {
    // For check in description
    $("#CheckinDescription").text("Some default text goes here.");
    // For version comments
    $("textarea[id$='CheckInComment']").text("First line\nSecond line\nThird line.");
 }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    addCommentDefaultValue();
});
```

Comment: I seem to be guilty of this more often than I like to admit. I neglected to indicate that I'm seeking a solution that works within the limitations imposed by Sharepoint Online.

Comment: The JavaScript approach is for SP online. Add that code into your custom JS file.

Comment: marked as answer

Comment: @Dmagner: Create your myCustomScript.js file in any of your favorite editor and upload it the the library.

Comment: Can the text be formatted in any way? I'd like to have it show .text("Some text: line break Some other text:")

Comment: Yes, see the edited answer.

Comment: You're a good man.